# Returning new form of array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My object:

```
const data = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "code": "ct101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2019-11-27T09:35:38.916Z",
    },
    {
      "code": "bt101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2016-11-27T08:20:57.297Z",
    },
  ]
}
```

There is a key called 'subscriptionExpiresOn' in my object inside rows array,

I want to check condition, If subscriptionExpiresOn is < new Date(). I need output like this:

```
// Changing the value into 'Expired'
const data = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "code": "ct101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2019-11-27T09:35:38.916Z",
    },
    {
      "code": "bt101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "Expired",
    },
  ]
}
```

Here what i tried using map method:

```
const now = new Date();

data.rows.map((index) => {
  if (index.subscriptionExpiresOn < now) {
    return {
      subscriptionExpiresOn: 'Expired',
    };
  } else {
    return data;
  }
});
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to mutate the same array, you should use **Array.forEach**. And for date comparison, you will need to convert string into date object.

```js
const now = new Date();
const data = {"rows": [{"code": "ct101","username": "admin","subscriptionExpiresOn": "2019-11-27T09:35:38.916Z"},{"code": "bt101","username": "admin","subscriptionExpiresOn": "2016-11-27T08:20:57.297Z"}]};

data.rows.forEach(o => {
  if(new Date(o.subscriptionExpiresOn) < now) o.subscriptionExpiresOn = 'Expired'
});
console.log(data.rows);
```

Comment: I am getting 'null' as value inside my 'subscriptionExpiresOn' key.?

Comment: @MohamedSameer - What is the expected result in that case? And `null` as in string "null" or `null`

Comment: @MohamedSameer - What needs to be done in that case? What is the expected output?

Comment: Ok wait, i think problem is in my side, will update you.

Comment: @MohamedSameer - okay. If still null value comes and you need no change in that case, you will need to update your condition to following `if(o.subscriptionExpiresOn && new Date(o.subscriptionExpiresOn) < now)`

Comment: Hey sorry, problem with my side, the value came as null because i have a datatype of subscriptionExpiresOn as a Date, so it returns null, if change to string, it works!

Comment: @MohamedSameer - Glad to help you!

Comment: Is there any way to implement this without changing the datatype? i need 'expired' as a value into my key rather than null.

Comment: The above should work because `new Date(null)` results in `Thu Jan 01 1970` which will be less than  `now`

Comment: I send the value as same as null, but in my frontend using if condition, if subscriptionExpiresOn == null, I am displaying as 'Expired" in my frontend.
Whether it is good approach?

Comment: @MohamedSameer - There are many solutions to a problem. Choose the one that suits you. There is no problem with the above too.

Answer (score 2):

You need a few changes. Firstly, you need to convert each `row.subscriptionExpiresOn` to a date object, so you can compare properly to `now`. Additionally, you need to return the row in addition to the updated key, so I'm using [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to accomplish this:

```js
const data = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "code": "ct101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2019-11-27T09:35:38.916Z",
    },
    {
      "code": "bt101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2016-11-27T08:20:57.297Z",
    },
  ]
}

const now = new Date();

const mapped = data.rows.map((row) => {
  if (new Date(row.subscriptionExpiresOn) < now) {
    return {
      ...row,
      subscriptionExpiresOn: 'Expired',
    };
  } else {
    return row;
  }
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Then if you're trying to preserve the structure, just return it in the original format:

```
return { rows: mapped };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because:

- the signature of `map` is a function whose first argument is the item, not the index;
- you're returning only what you want to change. Instead, return the whole object, overwriting the old value with the new;
- in the else branch, you're returning the whole original array instead of just returning the item as it is;
- you're comparing a stirng with a date.

Here's the working code.

```js
const data = {
  "rows": [
    {
      "code": "ct101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2019-11-27T09:35:38.916Z",
    },
    {
      "code": "bt101",
      "username": "admin",
      "subscriptionExpiresOn": "2016-11-27T08:20:57.297Z",
    },
  ]
}

const now = new Date();

const result = data.rows.map((item) => {
  if (new Date(item.subscriptionExpiresOn) < now) {
    return {
      ...item,
      subscriptionExpiresOn: 'Expired',
    };
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});

console.log(result)
```